# How to create tree grid in giu imgui library?

Tags: go, imgui

I'm using [giu](http://github.com/AllenDang/giu), which is a Golang port of imgui,

I need a tree grid like this:

[image]

The image can be found at [imgui](https://github.com/ocornut/imgui), but I don't find the implementation in the repository, I tried this:

```golang
package main

import (
    "github.com/AllenDang/giu"
    "github.com/AllenDang/imgui-go"
)

func loop() {
    row1 := giu.TableRow(
        giu.TreeNode(`parent`).Layout(
            giu.TableRow(
                giu.TreeNode(`child`),
                giu.Label(`ch1`),
                giu.Label(`ch2`),
            ),
        ),
        giu.Label(`p1`),
        giu.Label(`p2`),
    )

    giu.SingleWindow(`win`).Layout(
        giu.Table(`table`).Columns(
            giu.TableColumn(`Column_1`),
            giu.TableColumn(`Column_2`),
            giu.TableColumn(`Column_3`),
        ).Rows(row1),
    )
}

func main() {
    wnd := giu.NewMasterWindow("app", 400, 300, 0)
    imgui.StyleColorsLight()
    wnd.Run(loop)
}
```

But it looks like:

[image]

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps but if you reorder the elements it works kid of like you want.

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/AllenDang/giu"
    "github.com/AllenDang/imgui-go"
)

func loop() {
    row1 := giu.TableRow(
        giu.Label(`p1`),
        giu.Label(`p2`),
        giu.TreeNode(`parent`).Layout(
            giu.TableRow(
                giu.Label(`ch1`),
                giu.Label(`ch2`),
                giu.TreeNode(`child`),
            ),
        ),
    )

    giu.SingleWindow(`win`).Layout(
        giu.Table(`table`).Columns(
            giu.TableColumn(`Column_1`),
            giu.TableColumn(`Column_2`),
            giu.TableColumn(`Column_3`),
        ).Rows(row1),
    )
}

func main() {
    wnd := giu.NewMasterWindow("app", 400, 300, 0, nil)
    imgui.StyleColorsLight()
    wnd.Run(loop)
}
```

Comment: It looks strange, but the idea is interesting.